# Unrecognised and undiscoverable(?) device on home network

Tags: network, nmap, router, network-scanners, configuration

I noticed yesterday that my home router (ASUS) was picking up an unrecognised device in it's traffic monitor function.  This is a  GUI that shows total upload/downloads by device/MAC address.

So this unrecognised MAC address is shown to be currently uploading data, at a slowish rate (around 200MB/day).  I googled the first section and found the manufacturer is Alcatel.

Before changing passwords etc I thought I'd try to discover more about it, but here's the weird thing, I can't discover it.  I have tried using nmap, looking in arp tables of various machines, broadcast pinging, I cannot see it at all. No other function on the router shows it, just the traffic monitor bit.  I've set up a wireshark capture filtering for this MAC, but nothing shows up.

So what's going on? I can still see the traffic counter going up, and it appears to be a real MAC, but it's not discoverable by any of the means I know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you set up your computer as an access point with identical settings as your router (including its BSSID) using `hostapd` on Linux? That way the rogue device should connect to your computer and you'll be guaranteed to see its traffic if there is any.

Comment: Have you tried with arping ?

Comment: I have tried arping yes, I just get "Unknown host <MAC>"

Comment: I will try to do as you suggest Andre, when I get chance. This weekend probably.

Answer (score 4):

It occurred to me what this was after a couple of days. It was traffic being 'uploaded' to the router from the modem.  I googled and sure enough Alcatel provide the modems for my broadband provider (BT).